# Cloudera Manager Health Issue: NameNode Connectivity, Web Server Status

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

Below is a snapshot of the health issues reported on CM. The datanodes in the list keep changing. Some errors from the datanode logs :

```
3:59:31.859 PM  ERROR   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode 
    datanode05.hadoop.com:50010:DataXceiver error processing WRITE_BLOCK operation  src: /10.248.200.113:45252 dest: /10.248.200.105:50010
    java.io.IOException: Premature EOF from inputStream
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doReadFully(PacketReceiver.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doRead(PacketReceiver.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.receiveNextPacket(PacketReceiver.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receivePacket(BlockReceiver.java:414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receiveBlock(BlockReceiver.java:635)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.writeBlock(DataXceiver.java:564)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.opWriteBlock(Receiver.java:103)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.processOp(Receiver.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:221)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
5:46:03.606 PM  INFO    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode 
    Exception for BP-846315089-10.248.200.4-1369774276029:blk_-780307518048042460_200374997
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.248.200.105:50010 remote=/10.248.200.122:43572]
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doReadFully(PacketReceiver.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doRead(PacketReceiver.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.receiveNextPacket(PacketReceiver.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receivePacket(BlockReceiver.java:414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receiveBlock(BlockReceiver.java:635)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.writeBlock(DataXceiver.java:564)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.opWriteBlock(Receiver.java:103)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.processOp(Receiver.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:221)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Snapshot:

[image: Health Issues reported on CM]

I am unable to figure out the root cause of the issue. I can manually connect from one datanode to another without issues, I don't believe it is a network issue. Also, the missing blocks and under-replicated block counts change (up & down) as well.

Cloudera Manager : Cloudera Standard 4.8.1

CDH 4.7

Any help in resolving this issue is appreciated.

Update: Jan 01, 2016

For the datanodes listed as bad, when I see the dadanode logs, I see this message a lot...

```
11:58:30.066 AM INFO    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode 
Receiving BP-846315089-10.248.200.4-1369774276029:blk_-706861374092956879_36606459 src: /10.248.200.123:56795 dest: /10.248.200.112:50010
```

Why is this datanode receiving a lot of blocks from other datanodes around the same time? It seems that because of this activity the datanode cannot respond to the namenode request in time and thus timing out. All bad datanodes show the same pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question got answered

[hdfs data node disconnected from namenode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999192/hdfs-data-node-disconnected-from-namenode).
                                       Please check your firewall. Use

```
telnet ipaddress port
```

to check the connectivity.

Comment: I tried telnet and it connects to other nodes successfully.
It does not seem to be a firewall issue. A node that is listed as having a connectivity issue now ... does not appear on the list after few minutes. Its on and off.